# DefaultFieldSetMapper for only string based files in SpringBatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working with SpringBatch, I have a file with only string values(lname,fname and address).I do not want to do custom fieldsetmapper`(custom.pkg.CustomFieldSetMapper)` manually.Is there a way to have default field set mapper instead of writing my custom one.Because we have only string fields.

```
joe,miche,canada
vajbai,modi,uk
gandhi,sonia,usa


public class CustomFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        User u = new User();
        u.setLname(fieldSet.readString(0));
        u.setFname(fieldSet.readString(1));
        u.setAddress(fieldSet.readString(2));
    }
}


<beans:bean id="cvsFileItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <beans:property name="resource" value="classpath:file.csv" />

        <beans:property name="lineMapper">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <beans:bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <beans:property name="names" value="fname,lname,address" />                     
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="custom.pkg.CustomeFieldSetMapper" />
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html). It should be exactly what you're looking for (and can handle multiple datatypes with ease).

```
<bean id="fieldSetMapper"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="prototypeBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="prototypeBean" scope="prototype"
      class="com.your.package.and.Classname" />
```